# Not showing path to GC root in Flash Builder Profiler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am trying to use flash builder profiler to find memory leaks in a pretty large flex application. But I see a lot of objects appearing in the memory snapshot for which when I view their object references, I can't see the path to the GC root for them.

I see objects for which it shows "(0 paths)" when expanding but they still weren't garbage collected.

[Here is an image from the profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE0Bh.png)

Is this a known bug?

I am trying to find out in which cases it doesn't show the path to GC root.

Comment: GC is a lazy service and does not eat away each piece of junk immediately. It can actually lay dormant for quite a while if Flash Player/Runtime thinks there's not pressing urge to free some memory. To check if it is really a leak or just Flash Player being self you can by explicitly calling **System.gc();** which only works in Debug Flash Player or in AIR Runtime.

Comment: I tried calling System.gc and since I was using the profiler in flash builder, I can just use a button to call it from there, which I did too. But those objects never got cleared. Anyway, I found the memory leak and the profiler showing no paths to GC root for those objects is just a bug I guess. After finding the leak, I could see that there clearly was a path and there were a lot of objects that the profiler was showing deleted that actually weren't.